# Unable to authenticate with gcloud on Windows 10 - no OPENSSL_Applink error

Tags: authentication, openssl, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy a Python backend contained in a Docker container using Google Cloud Run. However, I'm running into issues during the authentication stage.

When I attempt to log in using the command gcloud auth login, I am successfully redirected to the authentication page in my browser. After completing the login process, the browser indicates that authentication was successful. However, there is no corresponding success message in the terminal. Instead, the terminal displays the following error:

> C:\Users\nicol\OneDrive\Documents\meal-planner\server>gcloud auth
> login Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> ```
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2F&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fsqlservice.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=GMDLeVQ8CBYmhLVP0sD67gHiP6t1BP&access_type=offline&code_challenge=M2E1mlP_TR4ZgP_MBSVmNsPn6yM0AciYTquZ3z4nufY&code_challenge_method=S256
> ```
>
> OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFDB4B39B50,08): no OPENSSL_Applink

I'm currently using Windows 10 and have the latest version of OpenSSL and the Google Cloud SDK installed.

I also tried to authenticate using a service account by creating a new role and generating a key in JSON format. I then attempted to authenticate using gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=.json, but this results in the same no OPENSSL_Applink error.

I am unsure of how to proceed as I have not been able to find any solutions or others with a similar issue online. I have also tried reinstalling both the Google Cloud SDK and OpenSSL to no avail.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: uninstall OpenSSL, reboot, and try again. My guess is that you have an app/package installed that is interfering with the CLI installation.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue on my PC by swapping out the SSL DLLs with files from another Python installation. You can try the following steps:

1. Download the "Windows embeddable package (64-bit)" at https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3913/
2. Unpack the downloaded archive.
3. From the extracted contents, copy the *libcrypto-1_1.dll* and *libssl-1_1.dll* files.
4. Replace the corresponding files in your Google Cloud SDK's bundled Python directory. In my case, the path was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\DLLs\
```

5. After this, the issue should be resolved.

For reference, I'm using Windows 10 and Google Cloud SDK version 449.0.0.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got same error after updating google cloud SDK and CLI. Could not find workaround. All google cloud actions resulted in this error. I installed google cloud on WSL2.

Followed this: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb and to install k9s I used method: https://gist.github.com/bplasmeijer/a4845a4858f1c0b0a22848984475322d

My quess is that specific version of gcloud messes up with openSSL library on Windows.My broken version:

Google Cloud SDK 443.0.0,
bq 2.0.96,
core 2023.08.11,
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0,
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.5.5,
gsutil 5.25